# How to solve angularjs Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view

I am developing a single page web application using AngularJS' ng-view and ng-template directives. But when I run it my browser show this type [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPuPo.png of error.

Here is my script block with main module and routing configuration.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>AngularJS - Views</title>
    
    <!--AngularJs Library-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h2 style="text-align: center;">Simple Application using AngularJS - Views</h2><hr><br>

      <!--Start AngularJS App-->
      <div ng-app="myApp">

        <p><a href="#addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
        <p><a href="#viewStudent">View Students</a></p>
        <div ng-view></div>

        <!--Script for Add Student-->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="addStudent.htm">
          <h2>This is the view of Add Student</h2>
          {{message}}
        </script>

        <!--Script for View Students-->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="viewStudent.htm">
          <h2>This is the view of all students</h2>
          {{message}}
        </script>

      </div>
      <!--End AngularJS App-->

      <!--App Necessary Scripts-->
      <script>
        
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

        myApp.config(['routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.

          when('/addStudent', {
            templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm', 
            controller: 'AddStudentController'
          }).

          when('/viewStudent', {
            templateUrl: 'viewStudent.htm',
            controller: 'ViewStudentController'
          }).

          otherwise({

            redirectTo: '/addStudent'

          });
        }]);

        myApp.controller('AddStudentController', function ($scope) {
          
          $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form!!";

        });

        myApp.controller('ViewStudentController', function($scope){

          $scope.message = "This page will be used to display   all students!!";

        });

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

what can I do to fix it?

Comment: have you add `angular-route` in your index file, seems that, you inject somethings that is not added

Comment: But I added it..
<!--AngularJs Library-->
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your working code. Also here's a CodePen example, I reorganize the code to make it more comfortable, please review it, study it and compare it for learning purpose. http://codepen.io/alex06/pen/rrzRbE?editors=1010

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Views</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
      <div>
         <p><a href = "#addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
         <p><a href = "#viewStudents">View Students</a></p>
         <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "addStudent.htm">
            <h2> Add Student </h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>
         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "viewStudents.htm">
            <h2> View Students </h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>
      <script>
         (function(){
            'use strict'
            angular
              .module('mainApp', ['ngRoute'])
              .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                  $routeProvider
                      .when('/addStudent', {
                         templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
                         controller: 'AddStudentController'
                      })
                      .when('/viewStudents', {
                         templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
                         controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
                      })
                      .otherwise({
                         redirectTo: '/addStudent'
                      });
                   }])
              .controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
                      $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
                   })
              .controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
                      $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
                   });
              })();   
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I added it...
<!--AngularJs Library-->
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>

Comment: take a screenshot of your index.html please.

Comment: Please see the link: Here I attached my index.html file screenshot
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8X9tpaFhNdKVkpZRUJHeDNZN1E?usp=sharing

Comment: Khandaker refer back to my previous answer image, it seems that you have not reference the module(myApp) and the controller on your index. Note that you are declaring (ng-app=" myApp") but the file is not referenced as well as the controller. See the picture I attached and the instructions I provided please.

Comment: Dear Alex, I learned from this link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm

Please see it. I have coded according to this tutorial. And I can't understood your previous answer image that what's my mistake. I added angularjs.min.js then angular-route.min.js and finally I Defined a script block with main module and set the routing configuration.

Comment: @KhandakerAkash please review my edited response with the code, if it helps you let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124666/discussion-between-alexp-and-khandaker-akash).

Comment: Now, I fixed it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the following line:

```
   myApp.config(['routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
```

To

```
    myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
```

I think this is what you missed.

Comment: Now, I fixed it, Thank u Sabbir brother.

Answer (score 0):

Define config as this:-- 
      myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) { $routeProvider

Rather than:-- myApp.config(['routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider.